# In Google Sheets, is it possible to align a row with Tilted Text to an untilted row above?

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, header, border, spreadsheet

I'd like to use a tilted header to compress a few groups of columns in my spreadsheet. If I just use one header row with Tilted Text, everything looks fine. Yet when I try to label the group of tilted columns by creating a row above (that is NOT tilted), the borders are disjointed.

Is there any way to make it so the left wall of the large merged cell in the top row is aligned with the slanted lefthand border of the tilted cell below?

[Screenshot of the misalignment, with red and blue annotation of where I want the borders to align](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2Al6.png)

I tried to see if tilting both rows would align the top row but it did not work, see this second screenshot: [Attempted to fix the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EALn.png)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Your showing images are the sample input situation? If my understanding is correct, can you provide the sample output situation you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.